# Which phrase is correct: "hell lord", or "lord of hell"?

Tags: phrases

I am wondering which phrase is correct, or maybe I can use both of them?

Comment: @sumelic I'd like to know if calling Satan "Hell Lord" would be correct

Answer (score 1):

**Which phrase is correct: “hell lord”, or “lord of hell”?**

I wondering which phrase is correct, or maybe I can use both of them?

This is not exactly a yes no situation Yes you can use both of them. However the pivotal point is How. Lord of hell is descriptive. **He was the Lord of Hell.** Or a name

Were as, Hell Lord could be a name, a book title or similar. For example **Hell Lord** is a World of War Craft Character,[WOWHEAD](https://www.wowhead.com/outfit=64952/hell-lord) Whilst Hell-Lords are Marvel Comic characters[MARVEL WEBSITE](https://www.marvel.com/teams-and-groups/hell-lords)

Comment: I would say a Hell Lord (or Hell-Lord) is some kind of lord who comes from, or is otherwise associated with, Hell. Lord of Hell, on the other hand, is Satan – the person who is lord over the land of Hell.

Comment: So calling Satan "Hell Lord" would be incorrect?

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet  Ah this is a difficult presumption. The statement " Lord of Hell, on the other hand, is Satan" is actually incorrect. It is commonly assumed that Satan is the Lord of Hell. However there is no statement to this effect in the Bible. Also there is no description of hell in the Bible, although it references what will happen there. Further more according to the Bible Hell is not yet occupied that will not happen until Judgement day. That is Why I have said Lord of Hell is descriptive, rather than related it to a statement which would have to be true/false.

Comment: @Brad I wasn’t talking biblically (I don’t believe in the existence of Hell or Satan to begin with); what the Bible actually says doesn’t really change things. My point was that “Lord of Hell” means “the master of Hell, the one who’s in charge in Hell”, which is what Satan’s day job is commonly presumed to be, whether the Bible actually says it or not. This differs from “Hell-Lord”, which is a lord probably from Hell, or at least somehow associated with it, but not as its master.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet; Yes I can see that, I was trying to explain the reason I had written my answer in the way I did, not criticise you comment. If I had actually answered with the statement "Satan is the Lord of Hell" I would have been (and quite correctly) open to criticism because I had not made a truthful statement  (there is no evidence to back up that statement). Also I have referenced the Bible in my comments not for religious reasons but because it is the definite source of information on this topic/

Comment: Thank you all for answers. So calling for example Satan "Hell Lord" would be incorrect?